# No-egg egg-wash

Tags: substitutions

Is there anyway to get sesame/poppy/etc. seeds to stick to a loaf of bread without using an egg wash?

A family member with an egg allergy means that I cannot use eggs anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can brush with melted butter, oil, milk, cream, honey, maple syrup, yogurt...water would even likely work.